# What did I do wrong here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

I can't for the life of me figure out what I did wrong with this question. 
[Alternatives to ApacheBench for profiling my code speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083523/alternatives-to-apachebench-for-profiling-my-code-speed)

- I asked about a fairly broad topic that is of general interest.
- I asked a specific, answerable question.
- I bumped it a couple times.
- I put a bounty of 200 rep on it.

And I have 30 views in 6 days.

Where did I go wrong?

Am I falling prey to the tl;dr effect? Not enough bullet lists and freehand circles? Some insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I found it hard to get past "I've done some experiments using Apache Bench to profile my code response times". I read that and have no idea what's going on anymore. I can guess that Apache Bench is some sort of benchmarking tool (though I had to google it to find out exactly what), but the concept of code response time is new to me. That probably means I'm not in your target audience, of course.

Comment: Interesting. I guess programming in web frameworks makes me a bit myopic about the topic. `ab` is a pretty standard tool to start to make sure your server won't melt the moment you get real traffic.

Comment: You might have a bit of luck on Serverfault with this question. A lot of system admins are responsible for load testing HA setups, using code that they didn't write (i.e. Wordpress / Joomla / Magento). You might find some help over there.

Comment: Yeah, I debated between the two when posting it. I was hoping for numbers that were a bit more raw than most load testing tools provide, but you're right. Maybe I should open a thread there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but did you.. sacrifice a chicken? Or ask about it on meta? I guess that's the same thing now that I think about it.

The question looks reasonably clear to me, but it is a tad open-ended. You might wait until the bounty closes (naturally pushing the question to the top of the featured tab) before concluding it's not working.

Comment: Did he ask about it on meta?... Uh...

Comment: @jon right, that's why it's funny..

Comment: I think we need to have a talk.

Comment: @Jon B: But you are having a talk... Uh...

Comment: @Michael right, that's why it's... oh, nevermind. You win.

Comment: Glad there's nothing obviously wrong with it. I've done bounties before, but usually had pretty good answers pretty quickly. I suppose it would be nice to be able to shorten the length of time on the bounty clock - sometimes I need an answer to a hard problem NOW, not 9-10 days after I asked the question.

Answer (score 5):

Most of my "interesting" tags are programming languages, frameworks, and specific related technologies. Your tags are:

`[profiling]` `[benchmarking]` `[latency]` `[apachebench]`

The only real specific tag is `[apachebench]`, which only has 15 questions in total. The other tags are very general.

If you can retag this with something more broadly appealing and specific, I think you'll see better results.

Comment: I suppose tagging it with `Python`, while only obliquely related, would probably put more eyes on it, since that's my preferred hammer. Good point though.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you get 90% of your bounty views during the last 10% of the 7 days =)

Give it time, I opened a few bounties and always thought they weren't effective because views remained the same, but then they skyrocketed during the last day and I always got an answer.

Comment: right, this is exactly how eBay works as well -- since most of the default sorts are "ending soonest".

Comment: Good to hear that the last couple days are likely to garner more interest. Pity that it takes a whole week to get to that point.

Comment: @Jeff The way eBay works actively **encourages** people to bid only at the last minute. Bounties don't really work the same way - if you answer a bounty question in the last 5 seconds then you won't get anything because nobody has had a chance to upvote you!

Comment: @kragen more people are looking toward the end as you get to the top of the list. More people looking = more opportunity for upvotes.